# magento changeResetPasswordLinkToken

Tags: magento, fatal-error, change-password

I have recently upgraded to Magento CE 1.8 and now when I submit the Forgot Your Password page it returns to a blank page.  It does not add any log into the exceptions.log file.  I have tracked the error down to the function `changeResetPasswordLinkToken` in /app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Customer.php

The error is on the line: `$this->saveAttribute($customer, 'rp_token')`; of the function `changeResetPasswordLinkToken`.

The site is using a custom template, I have verified that the template does have the customer_account_resetpassword code in the customer.xml.

Has any run into this?  Could this have been caused by an error during the upgrade to 1.8?  How do I go about fixing this?

After more digging I tracked it further down to this file:
/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php

Function:

```
saveAttribute(Varien_Object $object, $attributeCode)
```

Line # 1535:

```
$attribute = $this->getAttribute($attributeCode);
```

`$attribute` is null at this point

After even more digging it appears that the eav_attribute table does not have a record for rp_token or for rp_token_created_at.

Are these 2 attributes new to Magento version 1.8?  Did they not get added when upgrading to 1.8?

Answer (score 0):

`rp_token` and `rp_token_created_at` have been added in Magento version 1.6.1.0 as we can deduce from the file `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/sql/customer_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.6.0.0-1.6.1.0.php`

You should check the database table `core_resource` for the entry `customer_setup` and check which version is listed in the resulting row. If this is >= 1.6.1.0, than this attribute should have been created. If not, you should try running your upgradescripts another time.

Comment: It has 1.6.1.1 for version and data_version for customer_setup.  ANy other ideas what I should for now?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. Try running the upgradescripts again (by changing the database versions for customer_setup to 1.6.0.0).